# Map-reduce using java - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, apache-spark, iterator, stringindexoutofbounds

I am trying to write a Spark application which outputs the number of words that start with each letter. I am getting a String index out of range error. Any suggestions, or am I not approaching this map-reduce problem in the right way?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        //Tell spark to access a cluster
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        System.out.printf("%d lines\n", sc.textFile("pg100.txt").count());


        //MARK: Mapping
        //Read target file into an Resilient Distributed Dataset(RDD)
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("pg100.txt");

        //Split lines into individual words by converting each line into an array of words
        //Treat all words as lowercase
        //Ignore non-alphabetic characters
        JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator()).map(line -> line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]","").replaceAll("\\.", "").toLowerCase());

        //MARK: Sorting
        //Count the total number of words that start with each letter
        JavaPairRDD<Character, Integer> letters = words.mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<>(w.charAt(0), 1));

        //MARK: Reducing
        //Get count of number of instances of each word
        JavaPairRDD<Character, Integer> counts = letters.reduceByKey((n1,n2) -> n1 + n2);

        counts.saveAsTextFile("result");
        sc.stop();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet contains 31 lines, so it's unclear what do you mean by "line 33". Also you've posted java code with tag scala. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that some words consist only of the characters replaced by the following line:

```
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator()).map(line -> line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]","").replaceAll("\\.", "").toLowerCase());
```

As a result, some words become empty strings and still remain in `words` RDD, and when you try to access their index=0 you naturally receive the exception you have mentioned.

You probably thought that if map produced the empty string, it would not going to be included into `words`, that's not true.

UPD. You may filter-out empty strings this way:

```
words.filter(line -> !line.equals(""));
```

Comment: You're right. I have empty strings in my RDD when I output it. However, I'm having trouble filtering out the empty strings with a filter method.